# Why my FileReader returns null?

Tags: java

I have written the following progam, but somehow my FileReader writes null into the variable reader. In the next line the BufferdReader crashes with a NullPointerException.
I have copied the path into file, so I assume its correct.

```
public class MyPaintPanel extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//Bild einlesen
private BufferedImage image = null;
{
    try {
        File imageFile = new File ("C:/Users/M/workspace/Praktikum/lab4/geoPosition/OSM_BerlinerTor.png");
        image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error image not found.");
    }   
}


//Route einlesen
    {
    try {
        //Öffne Datei
        File file = new File("C:/Users/M/workspace/Praktikum/lab4/geoPosition/RouteGeo.txt");
        System.out.println("file = "+file);
        FileReader reader = FileReader(file);
        System.out.println("reader = "+reader);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        //Arbeite mit Datei

        while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
            System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
        }

        //Schließe Datei
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error file not found.");
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error file not found.");
    } finally {

    }
}

}
```

This is the output of my program. I added some System.out.println() to see what exactly is in the variables.

```
file = C:\Users\M\workspace\Praktikum\lab4\geoPosition\RouteGeo.txt
reader = null
java.lang.NullPointerException
Error file not found.
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at lab4.geoPosition.MyPaintPanel.<init>(MyPaintPanel.java:61)
at lab4.geoPosition.GeoGUI.<init>(GeoGUI.java:90)
at lab4.geoPosition.GeoGUI.main(GeoGUI.java:215)
```

Ok, I found the FileReader method, I think he autogenerate it, because its allmost empty.

```
private FileReader FileReader(File file2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The code you've given wouldn't even compile unless you've got a `FileReader` method that you haven't declared somewhere. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Here you go: new new new new (so you have some in stock :p)

Comment: Even if you meant `new FileReader(file)`, the `new` operator never returns null. So the only interpretation is that you do have a `FileReader(File)` method somewhere in your code that is returning null.

Comment: Well, you found it. `FileReader()` returns `null` and has a comment telling you to implement it to perhaps... return something other then `null`?

Comment: What exactly I have to change, to fix the problem? I have like no idea what I have to write in this method.

Comment: Delete the `FileReader(File)` method and use `FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);` instead, which is probably what it was supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks khelwood, that was exactly what I was trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forget to put `new` when you were instantiating the `FileReader`, and then auto-generated an empty method called `FileReader` to make it compile.

You don't need the `private FileReader FileReader(File file2)` method definition at all. You just need to change the line

```
FileReader reader = FileReader(file);
```

to

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
```

so that it is calling the constructor of `FileReader`, not looking for a method called `FileReader`.